# Html.ActionLink Textbox Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

I need to put this value:

```
  @Html.DropDownList("region", new[]{ 
           new SelectListItem() { Text = "MA", Value = "MA" },
                new SelectListItem() { Text = "BC", Value = "BC" },
                     new SelectListItem() { Text = "ON", Value = "ON" },

          })
```

into here:

```
@Html.ActionLink("<<", "List", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, zipCode = ViewData["zipCode"], searchType = ViewData["searchType"], distance = ViewData["distance"], region = ViewData["region"], country = ViewData["country"] })
```

ViewData["region"] is null and I cannot get the value, when I click the link. How do I put the DropDownList's region value into the query string? I set the region to a default of MA in my code:

```
public ViewResult List(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, string zipCode, string region, int? distance, string searchType, string country)
    {
        _storeService = new StoreService();

         //sets defaults
         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(zipCode))
         {
             zipCode = "02472";
         }

         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(region))
         {
             region = "MA";
         }
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the action link to update on the page, as the user changes the selection?  Or do you just want the values of "region" as it was on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't set the URL on page load, I'd just add a click listener to the anchor tag, and update the link there:

```
@Html.ActionLink("<<", "List", new { ... },
    new { onclick = "updateLink(this);" })
```

The handler should retrieve the region from the regions drop-down, and update the link's `href`:

```
function updateLink(anchor) {
    var select = document.getElementById('region');
    var region = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
    anchor.href = e.href + "&region=" + region;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

When user see your page it has already been rendered with link values, and i guess you want the selected value to be placed in that link after user made her choice. Client-side thing.
From your code - you pass to the controller a value from ViewData["region"] which isn't populated on the controller from the first place. That's why you get null.
Use ajax to populate viewdata on selection changed.